# run c program at startup

Tags: linux

I am a beginner to linux programming. What I want to do is, run a C "Hello World" program at startup. Once the user logs in, run that C program. How can I achieve this?

I am running Ubuntu 8.04.

Comment: [Desktop Application Autostart Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html)

Comment: This is distribution and desktop dependant. Are you using gnome? KDE?

Comment: This has everything to do with linux and nothing to do with C. Running a program is running a program; it doesn't matter what language was used to write the program.

Comment: you want to run it in the background?

Comment: "run program at startup" and "run when user log in" are two different things. Which do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

you can create a script inside `/etc/init.d/myScriptName` which inside this script you start you program

remember to give `chmod +x` to your script to give execution permissions

Answer (score 1):

I've done that on my machine.

First, in your menu bar, click **System**, then **Preferences**, then click **Sessions**.

A list of startup programs will be shown. click + button and add your script.

This might differ on linux distro. But at least you got the idea.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by writing a bash script