# Automatically run a program on startup under Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, startup

I'd need a program to be run every time I start up my Ubuntu Linux. So I'd need to add it to my startup programs list. Just one problem: I'd need to do it via the terminal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080315/linux-equivalent-for-windows-startup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424703/run-c-program-at-startup and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358300/programmatically-run-at-startup-on-linux

Comment: @Flexo This answer is not present in neither of the links you provided. +1 to this question and answer

Comment: In fact, the answer here is referenced from the first of those questions.

Comment: For a simple, portable way to do this, you can use Cron. Run `crontab -e` to edit your user's crontab; add `@reboot command` to run `command` on each boot.

Comment: I dont know if its a duplicate or not but it is the first google hit..

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57197654/8460132) out. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 183):

```
sudo mv /filename /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/filename 
sudo update-rc.d filename defaults
```

The script should now start on boot. Note that this method also works with both hard links and symbolic links (`ln`).

At this point in the boot process PATH isn't set yet, so it is critical that absolute paths are used throughout. *But*, as pointed out in the comments by Steve HHH, explicitly declaring the full file path (`/etc/init.d/filename`) for the update-rc.d command is not valid in most versions of Linux. Per the [manpage for update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/update-rc.d.8.html), the second parameter is a script located in `/etc/init.d/*`.

Also as pointed out in the comments (by Charles Brandt), `/filename` must be an init style script. A good template was also provided - *[System V init script template](https://github.com/fhd/init-script-template)*.

As pointed out in the comments (by Russell Yan), this works only on default mode of *update-rc.d*.

According to the manual of update-rc.d, it can run on two modes: "the machines using the legacy mode will have a file `/etc/init.d/.legacy-bootordering`", in which case you have to pass sequence and runlevel configuration through command line arguments.

The equivalent argument set for the above example is

`sudo update-rc.d filename start 20 2 3 4 5 . stop 20 0 1 6 .`

Comment: Just as an FYI, the option “defaults” puts a link to start the script in run levels 2, 3, 4 and 5. (and puts a link to stop in 0, 1 and 6.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check it as soon as possible! Do you know if it is possible to do something like this on a mac computer as well? It should be a unix os not unlike linux... so do you know if there's any similar way to do this on mac as well? Thank you again!

Comment: Macs a lot easier. Just put the script in the Login Items list in your Accounts preferences

Comment: I just tried this in Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, but in 12.04 you can't have the /etc/init.d prefix. It's just `sudo update-rc.d filename defaults`.

Comment: This does not run in an X terminal, he apparently wants to do it on starting the desktop.  I gave some sort of answer here http://superuser.com/questions/528930/open-terminal-on-start-and-pass-a-command

Comment: can we set up a link instead of physically moving the program?

Comment: @puk Both hard links and symbolic links will work with this method

Comment: This does not work for me. I have "Ubuntu Server 13.04" (Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-30-generic #44-Ubuntu). I just tried to run my ***/etc/init.d/emacs-server*** (`emacs --daemon`) command on boot, using these instructions. Anything different I need to do?

Comment: @Nutritioustim - I am able to run `emacs --daemon` on boot using the instructions provided. What error message are you receiving? Did you remember to include the shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) at the top of your script file?

Comment: @Dave, actually, my ***./etc/init.d\/emacs-server*** has `#!/bin/bash emacs --daemon`. When I look at ***var/log/boot.log ***, I get an `/etc/rc2.d/S20emacs-server: line 3: emacs: command not found` error message. See [link](http://pastie.org/8391967).

Comment: @Nutritioustim - That means that emacs is not in root's environment variables. Run `which emacs` to find the full path of emacs. At this point, you can either add the directory into root's path or just use the full path in your `emacs-server` script (most likely `/usr/bin/emacs`). I would recommend the latter

Comment: @Dave, Did that. But I still get the error [here](http://pastie.org/8393507). I tried `/usr/local/bin/emacs --daemon --with-x-toolkit=lucid`, as per log suggestion. But no dice :/

Comment: @Nutritioustim - Sorry, I don't have much experience in emacs so I'm not too sure how to guide you from here. This looks to be an issue on their end :/

Comment: Just wanted to add that /filename in this case should be an init style script. Here is a template for starting your own custom init script: https://github.com/fhd/init-script-template

Comment: Reading this - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28679/whats-the-connection-between-etc-init-d-and-etc-rcx-d-directories-in-linu - along with the answer will be helpful

Comment: Does "Should be an init style script" mean it's mandatory or can it be anything?

Comment: It must be an init style script. Updated verbiage

Comment: This works only on default mode of update-rc.d. According to manual of update-rc.d, it can run on two modes, "the machines using the legacy mode will have a file /etc/init.d/.legacy-bootordering", in which case you have to pass sequence and runlevel configuration through command line arguments.

Comment: @CharlesBrandt , I still need to run `/etc/init.d/algorithms start` command. But I want it would run **automatically** in startup. Is there a way?

Comment: To uninstall the script use update-rc.d filename remove

Comment: worked like a charm for one daemon. however when i tried to use it for 'tranmission-gtk --minimized' it didn't work. So, I tried '$ gnome-session-properties' and it worked.

Comment: This answer is obsolete as of 2020.