# vncconfig unable to automatically work at startup

Tags: linux, unix, ksh, vnc

I am using vnc to connect to a linux system (redhat). Everytime I want to copy/paste things from windows to linux, I had to start vncconfig. I searched in internet on how to automatically start vncconfig at startup. The line is like vncconfig -nowin &. I put this line in ~/.vnc/xstartup file.

But this is not working. I had to type again the command vncconfig in terminal to enable copy paste. Please help.

Comment: You need to create a startup script. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu

Comment: I start vncconfig with an /etc/xdg/autostart/ `.desktop` file. It calls a script which checks if running in vnc, and starts vncconfig if needed, like this: `xdpyinfo | grep -q VNC && exec vncconfig -nowin`

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are starting vncconfig after either an exec line or after the window manager, when it should be before.  It would be good to get a copy of your script posted to have a look if you are still looking for an answer.