# Arch linux startup application (script) Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, linux, mono, raspberry-pi, archlinux

I want to use an RPi running Arch Linux to power an embedded device and I therefore need the RPi to launch a (Mono C#) application the moment after it has finished booting without the user having to do anything. I have seen tutorials of how to do this on Raspbian but not for Arch. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016713/how-to-run-command-at-startup-in-linux

Comment: Also here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19634/linux-equivalent-for-windows-startup, and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: All the above answers do not seem to work on Arch linux

Comment: systemd is the way to go. You should write a service file for your application. It's well documented in the wiki : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_custom_.service_files

Comment: If you have a desktop environment installed on your RPi there are easier solutions than systemd depending on your DE. Otherwise systemd is the solution you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Systemd should do the trick.  Create a service file for systemd:

```
vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/*yourApp*.service
```

The service file will need to contain at a minimum the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=My C# application

[Service]
ExecStart=<fully qualified path to your C# application>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You should then be able start the service using

```
systemctl start yourApp
```

you can quickly see if it worked or if there are any errors using

```
systemctl status yourApp
```

Once your happy that its working enable the service to start automatically using:

```
systemctl enable yourApp
```

use the link to the arch wiki provided by dna to learn more about more options for systemd files [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_custom_.service_files)