# send packetdata from tshark to wireshark

Tags: raspberry-pi, wireshark, sniffing, tshark

I want to run `tshark` on a `Raspberry Pi` after booting or for a defined period of time and save the captured packets into a file. This file should then be accessible from `Wireshark` on my `Windows` laptop. I want to do this because I want to capture packets for example when I am not at home and then can analyze the captured data when I am back home. Is that possible? How can I start capturing after booting or for a defined period of time into a file and then send it to `Wireshark` on my laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tcpdump -s 0 -i eth0 -W 1 -w dump.pcap -G 3600 port ftp or http
```

Will keep writing all matching packets to dump.pcap for 3600 seconds. You can then copy that file to your machine and load it normally with Wireshark's open dialog.

You could also use `dumpcap` or even `tshark` if you want, but tcpdump is well suited for this.

As for running on system startup, checkout:
[Run automatically program on startup under linux ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu) or just append your `tcpdump` line with an `&` at the end to `/etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on your host machine.

ssh user@remotehost /usr/local/bin/tshark -l -w - | wireshark -k -i -

This opens a tshark on the remote machine and connects it to the wireshark on your local machine.