# windows java program as a service in linux?

Tags: java

I created one java class which is connected to the online DB. I want to use my java code in Linux. But I want that code run continuously in the Linux system in a background.
Or else how to use a wrapper class?

Comment: Your question is not very detailed. Please give us some more detail.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Java is platform independent, all you need is a JRE installed on the system. As for the rest of your question it's not very clear what you're trying to ask. I don't see the connection between running a program in the background and using a wrapper class, can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run automatically program on startup under linux ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7221757/5221149), which itself is a duplicate of [Linux equivalent for Windows Startup](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19634) on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Java is Plattform **independend** as long as you **dont** use any os-related libraries. 
As there are JDBC drivers for Unix and windows, this should not make a problem.

But remember to install the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) with the same version you created the application for.

You can pack it into a jar and call it with

```
java -jar <path>
```

You can run it in the background in different ways  like forking it or creating a second terminal, use screen and call the java command.

Comment: Did you mean JDBC?