# How to autostart a c++ program on raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I mean when I power up the pi my c++ file should be automatically executed. Please anyone guide me through steps. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu

Comment: This has nothing to do with c++. Just configure the executable generated from the c++ source in your inittab.

Comment: create a systemd unit file for your program...  https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution that works on bootup to the console, take a look at this link. Basic rundown:

Create a file for your startup script and write your script in the file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/init.d/superscript
```

Save and exit: Ctrl+X, Y, Enter

Make the script executable:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/superscript
```

Register script to be run at startup:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d supersc
```